# Cancel google cloud endpoint request

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints for communication between Android client and backend.
I am interested in following scenario:
User enters MessageFragment, which sends a request to backend (in AsyncTask) to obtain a most recent list of messages. Before the request has finished, user leaves MessageFragment and enters FragmentA. FragmentA wants to start another AsyncTask and send another request to backend, but this AsyncTask has to wait until the first AsyncTask is finished. My question is how can I cancel a cloud endpoint request so that the application can work more "smooth". It's not strictly necessary that the server stops execution of the request, only that the client stops waiting for the response.
I have been thinking of using the parallel execution of AsyncTasks, but I am a little aware of concurrency errors.
I tried to find the `cancel` or `abort` ... methods in xEndpointRequest, but I didn't find.

Comment: I'm not an Android expert, but does calling `asyncTask.cancel(true)` not interrupt the request? See [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues/172); it is a long standing feature request to be able to cancel requests directly.

Comment: I have tried it, I have also expected the behavior that the thread executing the request interrupt, but it wasn't the case.